# jQuery Accordion - scroll to the top and body 100% height not working together

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, accordion, conflict

I have an accordion that when I open one of the items it scrolls down at the end so I have to scroll up manually in order to see the header.
I am using this

```
$(".ui-accordion-header").click(function(event, ui) {
    $("html, body").scrollTop($(this).position().top);
});
```

I want also to have my footer always at the bottom of the page so I have to use this css:

```
 html,body{
    height:100%;
 }
```

But this thing is not working. If I remove the 100% on css then it works but another parts of my pages are broken. 
So is there any way to keep height of html and body on 100% and make the scroll to work too?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you supply a link to the live server?

Comment: I would instead try to figure out why the accordion is scrolling to the end.

Comment: it is a test server so I cannot really supply the link. I think it scrolls down because of the big content of the accordion

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle then?  Without seeing it it's difficult to help.

Comment: actually I just noticed that the problem is that I have html,body{height:100%}. If I remove this css then the accordion works. But I want to keep this, so is there any way to make the accordion scroll to top but keeping html and body on 100% ?

Comment: I edited also the question a bit.